# Path needs to be broken out into seperate rows instead of combined into one

Tags: powershell, csv

I am close to getting this completed but have one problem.  In the CSV file, I need to break out the the paths into seperate rows instead of having all the paths in one record of the csv.

My goal is to clean up redundant GPO's. I need to search the xml files from a GPO backup and analyze them. If I find the same custom string in two or more GPO's, the path will show me which folder contains the redundant string and can either combine the GPO's or delete one all together. Makes sense .. I hope?

I have put an example of the output below:

```
"Count","Paths","Line"   
"5","C:\Users\user\Desktop\GPO Backup\{FBF5B657-2B31-4046-9A08-406221481FE1}\gpreport.xml|C:\Users\user\Desktop\GPO Backup\{FD297204-7AAE-4A19-AC59-471D32FC34DC}\gpreport.xml|C:\Users\user\Desktop\GPO Backup\{FD6E7C80-5682-499A-A1B5-A38EF998BD3D}\gpreport.xml|C:\Users\users\Desktop\GPO Backup\{FE4AC515-9C11-40F0-9D2C-940C98CA4DDF}\gpreport.xml|C:\Users\user\Desktop\GPO Backup\{FE4E07F8-BFFB-455C-86FD-845EF5E473F4}\gpreport.xml","<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>"
```

---

```
$ht = @()
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter gpreport.xml
$files
foreach ($file in $files)
    {
         $path = $file.FullName
    $lines = Get-Content $path
    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        if ($match = $ht | where { $_.line -EQ $line })
           { 
            $match.count = $match.count + 1
            $match.Paths += $path
        }
        else
        {
            $ht += new-object PSObject -Property @{
            Count = 1
            Paths = @(, $path)
            Line = $line
            }
        }
    }
}

$ht
$ht.GetEnumerator() |
select Count, @{ n = 'Paths'; e = { $_.Paths -join '|' } }, Line |
Export-Csv c:\temp\NLG_GPO_Sort.csv
```

Comment: I have added the goal of the script in the orignal post @Pet

Comment: Am I missing something? Those paths look unique to me

Comment: Damn @Matt .. you are right .. just noticed that.  I am going to change the title to what I really need done.

Comment: The blockquote was masking the line that was match in the 3rd column. It is a long line of text though. I changed it to code format

Comment: Are you asking for variable column output then? You would be better of making your own CSV output then

Comment: Thanks @Matt I could not figure out how to do that.

Comment: I did change the title to what the real problem is.  Thanks for catching the result error I made.

Comment: So, what expected result should look like?

Comment: Can you provide an example @matt of what you are talking about?

Comment: Like PetSerAI.... it would be better if you first show us what you want.

Comment: Instead of the paths being in one row, it would be great if  could have each path one under the other.  I know this can be done in Excel .. but not sure about a csv file.

Comment: You've gone out of your way to combine the paths together and now you want them split out.  I suggest simplifying.  Do one line in $ht for every $line in every $file.  Get rid of the 'counts field.  Get more of a raw data dump.

Then you can use powershell or excel to do whatever.